# Error will not parse citations in the form `\cite[text]{citation}`

Tags: errors, citing

I am having an error with the Science Journal.

`\cite` command  ONLY with LaTeX 2019, and ONLY when `\cite` is used with a precursor bracket for text:

```
\cite[text]{reference}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your question, though, is far too vague.  What error?  What TeX engine are you using?  Please also include a minimal working example.  These things will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: The plain-LaTeX `\cite` command does not recognize, let alone know what do with, an optional argument. For `\cite` to work with an optional argument, you *must* load a citation management package such as `cite`, `natbib`, `harvard`, `apacite`, and (last but not least) `biblatex`. Please tell us if that's the case in your document.